# How can i ping a container from other machine ? Using container ip ex:172.17.0.3

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

When i am trying to ping to container ex:172.17.0.3 .I am getting host unreachable.Please help me
Thank you.

Comment: You need to be more clear on what you tryed. Are you trying to ping from the host, machine in local network, through the internet?
Keep in mind that docker uses NAT.

Comment: I  am trying from different host in same network.

Comment: I got it. Thank you : )

Comment: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/221 This may help (it's for windows but the subjects is quite the same)